# Unable to create Elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create the elastic mapping

```
{
   "mappings": {
       "calls" : {
          "properties":
           {
             agent_id: {"type" : "string", 
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "fielddata": true}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> [mapper_parsing_exception] Mapping definition for [agent_id] has unsupported parameters:  [fielddata : true]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/fielddata.html) seems to be a property of `text` fields which have `"type" : "text"`